difference between analytical and numerical solutions for a PDE problem
first of all I'd like to point out that this is my first time using Stack Overflow so don't hesitate to tell me if something isn't displaying properly or isn't clear.
I'm trying to solve an advection equation with a second member whose analytical solution is known. I also wanted to test the method with a finite difference discretization. The results are similar, but there is a difference. I calculate the solution over four portions. For the first portion, the exact solution coincides with the analytical solution. For the second portion, the agreement is quite good, but errors still appear. The situation deteriorates for the third and fourth portions.
Here is the function that calculates the solutions analytically
function [C1, C2, C3, C4] = calcul_sol_analy(mesures,params)

    

    % Solution portion 1
    x_p1 = linspace(0, params.xcm, 100);        
    [X1, T1] = meshgrid(x_p1, params.t_values);
    C1 = params.c0(T1 - X1/params.v) .* exp(-params.k * X1 / params.v);   

    % Solution portion 2
    Cm =  interp1(params.date_jours_ch, mesures, params.t_values, 'pchip')';  % transposée 
    x_p2 = linspace(params.xcm, params.xcp, 100);  
    [X2, T2] = meshgrid(x_p2, params.t_values);
    c1 = @(t) (C1(:, end) .* params.debit_s + Cm .* params.debit_m) ./ (params.debit_SM);
    C2 = c1(T2 - (X2-params.xcm)/params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X2-params.xcm)/ params.v);   
 
    % Solution portion 3
    
    Cp = interp1(params.date_jours_cl, params.mesures_crassphage_ch, params.t_values, 'pchip')'; % transposée 
    x_p3 = linspace(params.xcp, params.xco, 100); 
    [X3, T3] = meshgrid(x_p3, params.t_values);
    c2 = @(t) (C2(:, end) .* params.debit_SM + Cp .* params.debit_cl) ./ (params.debit_SME);
    C3 = c2(T3 - (X3-params.xcp)/params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X3-params.xcp)/ params.v); 

    % Solution portion 4
   
    Co = interp1(params.date_jours_tr, params.mesures_crassphage_ch, params.t_values, 'pchip')'; % transposée
    x_p4 = linspace(params.xco, params.xct, 100); 
    [X4, T4] = meshgrid(x_p4, params.t_values);
    c3 = @(t) (C3(:, end) .* params.debit_SME + Co .* params.debit_o) ./ (params.debit_SMO);
    C4 = c3(T4 - (X4-params.xco)/params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X4-params.xco)/ params.v);

end

and here is the function that calculates the solutions numerically
function [C1, C2, C3, C4] = calcul_sol_num(mesures, params)

    % Solution portion 1
    C1 = zeros(params.Nt, params.Nx);
    C1(:, 1) = params.c0(params.t_values);
    x_p1 = linspace(0, params.xcm, params.Nx);  
    [X1, T1] = meshgrid(x_p1, params.t_values);
    C_exact = params.c0(T1 - X1 / params.v) .* exp(-params.k * X1 / params.v);
    C1(1, :) = C_exact(1, :);
    
    for n = 1:params.Nt-1
        for i = 2:params.Nx-1
            C1(n + 1, i) = C1(n, i) * (1 - params.k * params.dt - params.v * params.dt / params.dx) + ...
                           C1(n, i-1) * (params.v * params.dt / params.dx);
        end
        C1(n + 1, params.Nx) = C1(n + 1, params.Nx-1);
    end

    % Solution portion 2
    Cm =  interp1(params.date_jours_ch, mesures, params.t_values, 'pchip')';  % transposée 
    x_p2 = linspace(params.xcm, params.xcp, params.Nx);  
    [X2, T2] = meshgrid(x_p2, params.t_values);
    c1 = @(t) (C1(:, end) .* params.debit_s + Cm .* params.debit_m) ./ params.debit_SM;
    C2 = zeros(params.Nt, params.Nx);
    C2(:, 1) = c1(params.t_values);
    C_exact = c1(T2 - (X2-params.xcm) / params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X2-params.xcm) / params.v);
    C2(1, :) = C_exact(1, :);
    
    for n = 1:params.Nt-1
        for i = 2:params.Nx-1
            C2(n + 1, i) = C2(n, i) * (1 - params.k * params.dt - params.v * params.dt / params.dx) + ...
                           C2(n, i-1) * (params.v * params.dt / params.dx);
        end
        C2(n + 1, params.Nx) = C2(n + 1, params.Nx-1);
    end 

    % Solution portion 3
    Cp =  interp1(params.date_jours_cl, params.mesures_crassphage_ch, params.t_values, 'pchip')';  % transposée 
    x_p3 = linspace(params.xcp, params.xco, params.Nx);  
    [X3, T3] = meshgrid(x_p3, params.t_values);
    c2 = @(t) (C2(:, end) .* params.debit_SM + Cp .* params.debit_cl) ./ params.debit_SME;
    C3 = zeros(params.Nt, params.Nx);
    C3(:, 1) = c2(params.t_values);
    C_exact = c2(T3 - (X3-params.xcp) / params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X3-params.xcp) / params.v);
    C3(1, :) = C_exact(1, :);
    
    for n = 1:params.Nt-1
        for i = 2:params.Nx-1
            C3(n + 1, i) = C3(n, i) * (1 - params.k * params.dt - params.v * params.dt / params.dx) + ...
                           C3(n, i-1) * (params.v * params.dt / params.dx);
        end
        C3(n + 1, params.Nx) = C3(n + 1, params.Nx-1);
    end 

    % Solution portion 4
    Co = interp1(params.date_jours_tr, params.mesures_crassphage_oi, params.t_values, 'pchip')'; 
    x_p4 = linspace(params.xco, params.xct, params.Nx);  
    [X4, T4] = meshgrid(x_p4, params.t_values);
    c3 = @(t) (C3(:, end) .* params.debit_SME + Co .* params.debit_o) ./ params.debit_SMO;
    C4 = zeros(params.Nt, params.Nx);
    C4(:, 1) = c3(params.t_values);
    C_exact = c3(T4 - (X4-params.xco) / params.v) .* exp(-params.k * (X4-params.xco)  / params.v);
    C4(1, :) = C_exact(1, :);
    
    for n = 1:params.Nt-1
        for i = 2:params.Nx-1
            C4(n + 1, i) = C4(n, i) * (1 - params.k * params.dt - params.v * params.dt / params.dx) + ...
                           C4(n, i-1) * (params.v * params.dt / params.dx);
        end
        C4(n + 1, params.Nx) = C4(n + 1, params.Nx-1);
    end 

end

Discretization parameter :
Nx = 101;  

Tf = max(date_jours_ch);

dx = L / (Nx-1) ;
dt = dx / v;
x_values = 0:dx:L;              
t_values = 2:dt:Tf;  
Nt=length(t_values);

solution portion 1 :
enter image description here
solution portion 2 :
enter image description here
solution portion 3 :
enter image description here
solution portion 4 :
enter image description here

Looks OK to me as a question. But, because it's more "maths" than it is "code" related, I wonder if https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab might get you more answers?

thank you very much for your answer i will try your on this platform then.
